# CompositionContainer: How can I get the source class from an exported value

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef

if I have following exports

```
Class A 
    [Export(typeof(IFOOExport))]
    public   IFOOExport ExportedFunctions_FULL = new FunctionsExport
    {
        Sub = String.Empty;

    };

Class B
   [Export(typeof(IFOOExport))]
    public   IFOOExport ExportedFunctions_EMPTY = new FunctionsExport
    {
        Sub = String.Empty;

    };
```

then I get the list:

```
 var exp_list=   CompositionContainer.GetExportedValues<IFOOExport>();
```

I should have two elements in the list, and my question is:

How can I identify which one is export from ExportedFunctions_EMPTY which one come from   ExportedFunctions_FULL?

Comment: I tried CompositionContainer.Catalog.Parts.item.ExportDefinitions, but seems GetExportedValues do not accept a parameter like 'Catalog.Parts' or 'ExportDefinitions'

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the `GetType()` method and inspect the `FullName` property of the returned `Type` object.

```
foreach (var exp in exp_list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exp.GetType().FullName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but in my scenario, I got a null of exp.